# Laravel: "Impossible to create the root directory" when storing file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to store a file via AJAX to public folder in laravel, however when I submit the form I get the following message:

" message: "Impossible to create the root directory \"C:\xampp\htdocs\Restaurante1\storage\app\C:/xampp/htdocs/Restaurante1/public/img\".", exception: "League\Flysystem\Exception", file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Restaurante1\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php"

I'm trying to store the file into the following folder inside public directory: public > img >uploads

This is my JQuery code:

```js
console.log('new slider button clicked');
 
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', $('#sliders_title').val());
formData.append('body', $('#sliders_body').val());
formData.append('isVisible', $('#sliders_isVisible').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0);
formData.append('image', $('#sliders_image').prop('files')[0]);


$.ajax({

    async: true,
    url: '/sliders',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
        
    success: function (data) { 
        $('.form_valid_container').html('<span class="form_valid_text">✓ '+ data.success +'</span>');
     form.trigger("reset");
        console.log(data.success, data.errors);
    },

    error: function (data){
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log(errors);
 
     $.each(errors , function(){
            $('.form_error_container').html('<span class="form_error_text">✘ '+ errors.message +'</span>')
        }); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My controller method:

```js
public function store(StoreSlider $request)
{
    $uploadFile = $request->file('image');

    //generate random filename and append original extension (eg: asddasada.jpg, asddasada.png)
    $filename = str_random(6).'.'.$uploadFile->extension();

    // storing path (Change it to your desired path in public folder)
    $path = 'img/uploads/';

    // Move file to public filder
    $uploadFile->storeAs(public_path($path), $filename);
 
    $slider = new Slider();
    $slider->title = $request->title;
    $slider->body = $request->body;
    $slider->image = $path.'/'.$filename; // So that you can access image by url($slider->image);
    $slider->isVisible = $request->isVisible;
    $slider->save();
 
    return response()->json([
 
        'success' => 'Diapositiva guardada correctamente',
  'slider' => $slider,
    ]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: This is my config/filesystems

```js
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: show your `config/filesystems.php` file

Comment: edited the OP with the info

Comment: `$uploadFile->storeAs(public_path($path), $filename);` is your issue, change `public_path($path)` to something like `img` only, not a full on path

Comment: There is a problem, you trying to store file in storage directory `$uploadFile->storeAs(public_path($path), $filename)`, if you wan't store it in public directory you need to add new disk in `filesystems.php` and then use this in `storeAs()` function

Comment: @Derek i think he wan't store that file in public directory not in storage directory

Comment: @Rainmx93 which is bad practice and is against what laravel says to do

Comment: @Derek yes i know, better solution is to create symbolic link from `public/img/uploads` to `storage/app/public/img/uploads` and store all uploaded files in storage directory

Comment: yes, I want to store inside public folder, public > img > uploads

Comment: how can I create symbolic link?

Comment: In Windows you cannot create a true symbolic  link.  You can use hard links(mostly unsupported = does not work for most programs, try to click on My Documents in your home folder.) or use multiple mount points.

Comment: Any POST file method to public  access is poor practice, you open yourself to viruses, worms and spam.  Please include a validation process in between.

Comment: try to gives all rights(777) to the folder

Answer (score 1):

in your FileSystem, you need to create the driver disk.

```
'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('img/uploads'),
        'url' => '/img/uploads',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

and you can call in your controller storage

```
$uploadFile->storeAs('/', $filename, 'uploads');
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer might not be relevant this very question but should in case someone encounters the same problem I think might be of help. I encountered the same problem and I "**putFileAs**" which worked the same way as "**storeAs**" like so `$path = Storage::putFileAs('public/users_upload/'.$user->username, $File_to_be_moved, $file_name_to_store_as);` First parameter is for the path to your directory... [You can check the laravel documentation for more info here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads)